# How to hide the searchresultstableview once the table view cell is selected in the search display controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

i am working on searchdisplaycontroller. how to hide the searchresults tableview once a particular cell is selected in the table view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 [mySearchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```